# ef6 code first identity key in parent table as foreign key in child table

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, data-annotations

I am giving the description of my entity below .It will be more easy to understand

**Parent Entity**

```
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    [Required]
    public virtual string Invno { get; set; }

     [Key]
    [Column(Order =1)]
    [Required]
    public virtual string Customer { get; set; }


    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public virtual int Sslno { get; set; }


    public virtual ICollection<ChildEntity> ChildEntity { get; set; }
```

**Child Entity**

```
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    [Required]
    public virtual string Itemcode { get; set; }


    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [Required]
    public virtual double Price { get; set; }


    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    [Required]
    public virtual int Sslno { get; set; }


    [ForeignKey("Sslno")]
    public virtual ParentEntity ParentEntity { get; set; }
```

Giving me the error:

> The number of properties in the Dependent and Principal Roles in a relationship constraint must be identical

Note: I dont want to make Invno and customer as foreign key

Comment: A foreign key has to match up with the primary key of the table you are linking to.  So you either need to make the foreign key Invno and customer or you have to make ssnlno the primary key instead.

Comment: What is the question and what have you tried so far to fix the problem?

Comment: @Brad qusetion is how to make sslno foreign key without making the same primary key in in parent entity

Comment: You need to rethink your design. It doesn't make sense at all for the parent to have a key `Invno,Customer (int,string)` and then try to make a foreign key to it as `SslNo (int)`.

Comment: @Rob can u tell me the alternate design to it , thing here is that  customers have their own invno so invno  and customer are made composite key .

Comment: @juharr when working with database directly  ,I am able to to do the same .But in EF6 I am not able to achieve it

Comment: @Rob thanks for editing it ,its my first time to post a question

Comment: @user5419119 You are right that you can do that **if** working directly with database. The point is though that EF is more constrained than database and does not allow that. Think of it as limitation if you like. The only options when working with EF6 are the mentioned by juharr and Rob.

Comment: @Ivan Stoev  is it a bad design?

Comment: @user5419119 I don't want to judge, as you said, it is a valid db design. Unfortunately not supported by EF6.